# Pass upload status back to particular VC

Tags: ios, swift

I want to obtain upload status (%, success, failure) in VC1 from UploadtoServerVC (And UploadToServerVC will be dismissed before the upload starts). Below is an image of my VC flow.

[image: ViewControllerFlow]

In my UploadToServerVC, as soon as the user hits send, I am calling dismissViewControllerAnimated to go back to VC1 and have the upload code in progress inside UploadToServerVC (behind the scene, similar to Instagram) to continue to run until completion (By keeping strong self inside completion block). What I want to achieve  is to have some sort of progress bar in VC1 to display the progress or error if anything was encountered. So I want to grab the feed back from the upload code (below) from my VC1. My upload code looks  like the following

```
@IBAction func postBtnPress(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    // 2. Create upload request
    let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()

    // Track progress through an AWSNetworkingUploadProgressBlock with strong self to allow block to be able to execute properly even if VC was dismissed
    uploadRequest?.uploadProgress = {(bytesSent:Int64, totalBytesSent:Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend:Int64) in
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

            let progress = Float(totalBytesSent) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToSend)

            print(" totalBytesSent \(totalBytesSent) / totalBytesExpectedToSend \(totalBytesExpectedToSend) progress = \(progress * 100 ) %")
        })
    }

        // 3. Upload to Amazone S3
        let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager()
        transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: { (task: AWSTask) -> AnyObject? in

            if let error = task.error {
                // Send error back to VC1

            } else {
                // Send completion status to VC1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is how I present the VCs in section 1,2,3 as shown in the image

```
1. 
let vc1 = VC1()
let navController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: vc1)
self.navigationController?.presentViewController(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)

2.
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(uploadToServerVC, animated: true)

3.
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

I am thinking NSNotification might be the way to go. However, I am not sure if that is the best practice as it could become messy? Is there a better way or would the notification be the way to go?

Comment: check my ans if suits .. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just got to the level of complexity where you **need** a MVC structure in your app.  Keeping a view controller alive to do data processing when it's not part of the screen hierarchy any more is not a good architecture.

Consider creating a non-UI (Model) object to manage your data transfer.  `VC1` can register a progress block with the transfer object and `UploadToServerVC` can assign it work without worrying about surviving being dismissed.

Comment: That does sound like a sensible way to do. I am abit new to this and have always done it without much MVC structure (putting most things inside VCs). I was wondering if you can provide me with some example code or link to a good example where I can start to learn to create such "non UI Object (Model)" Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would create an uploader object. Then place this method inside the object. Create this object at a level both classes will have access (maybe a nav controller or globally).

Then dismiss the view controller and set a property in the object such as a bool 'shouldUpload' = true and then before view controller 1 appears start the upload (use the viewWillAppearMethod) only if it should upload otherwise it will do it everytime the view appears.

Finally configure the upload method in the object to also have a completion block. Then you can receive the progress updates every time it completes as it will come back to v1 or where ever the method was executed.

Comment: Would you be able to provide me with some example code as I am not familiar with the concept of creating uploader object. Traditionally, I have just been putting most things inside myVC. Or a link to a good tutorial would be good too:) Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

According to the approach if you consider you should opt class methods to return the progress value of uploaded file. I meant create class method in which write code to return progress value see example below ..

From uploadToServerVC when dismisView method called:

- set key using `NSUserDefaults` `true` or `false` accordingly if pic needs to upload or not and save pic data using `NSData` or in your way.
- Now navigate back to vc1.

Now inside vc1:

- Check key if true pass the data using `NSData` or according to you to class method and recieve the uploading progress accordingly.

Class method Inside `AppDelegate`:

```
class func returnProgress() -> Int {
    // this is example code here to upload and return progress value
    return 10
}
```

Calling class method from vc1 with uploading file data:

```
// pass data in order to get progress value this is an example
AppDelegate.returnProgress()
```

Comment: I have not use app delegate to do anything like that before. Is it a good idea to start putting code like this in it?

Comment: creating class methods in appdelegate or any other class is `re-usability`  of code without writing again and again so if you do not want to create class method you can put your upload progress code inside `vc1` and pass the uploading file data to it ..